# How to register user on ejabberd using php code?

Tags: php, sudo, ejabberd

I am trying to register user on ejabberd linux server.

I am using below php code

```
<?php
  $username = 'hello';
  $password = 'hello';
  $node = 'my ip';
  exec('sudo -S ejabberd /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl register '.$username.' '.$node.' '.$password.' 2>&1',$output,$status);
  if($output == 0){
        // Success!
        echo 'success';
   }else{
        // Failure, $output has the details
        echo '<pre>';
        foreach($output as $o){
                echo $o."\n";
        }
         echo '</pre>';
   }
?>
```

But when I execute the file i got following error :

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
        [sudo] password for daemon:
```

Also I found the solution from below url to put below code in configure.cfg

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

sudo in php exec()

but I am not getting how to use this

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Reading error messages is hard:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
```

You have incorrect permissions on the /etc/sudoers.d directory. That directory should not be world writeable (if you allow that (and sudo would accept it) then any user can grant themselves sudo privileges, which is a Bad Thing<sup>TM</sup>)
Fix that!

```
[sudo] password for daemon:
```

Hmmm. Your PHP code is running as the user `daemon` ...

Then granting sudo rights to the group `admin`  is probably not effective... Instead grant the correct rights to the right user. For syntax: [`man usedoers`](http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html)